# Spring Boot Slack Bot - allow deletion of messages

Tags: spring-boot, slack, slack-api

How can I allow a Slack Bot, implemented with Spring Boot, to delete a message?

The Spring Boot Slack Bot uses the simple-slack-api. When sending a deleteMessage the received reply is: **cant_delete_message**. So an authorisation issue.

The Slack Bot code is:

```
SlackSession session = SlackSessionFactory.createWebSocketSlackSession(slackToken);
session.connect();
SlackMessagePostedListener messagePostedListener = new SlackMessagePostedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(SlackMessagePosted event, SlackSession session) {
        if (session.sessionPersona().getId().equals(event.getSender().getId())) {
            return; // don't react on slack bot's own replies
        }
        SlackChannel channelOnWhichMessageWasPosted = event.getChannel();
        String messageContent = event.getMessageContent();
        SlackUser messageSender = event.getSender();
        if( messageContent.startsWith( "secret")) {
            session.sendMessage(event.getChannel(), "pssst: " + messageContent);
            SlackMessageHandle handle = session.deleteMessage( event.getTimeStamp(), channelOnWhichMessageWasPosted);
            logger.info( "Delete result : " + ((ParsedSlackReply) handle.getReply()).getErrorMessage());
        } else { ... }
    }
};
session.addMessagePostedListener(messagePostedListener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally users can only delete their own message, not the messages of others. Except for admins and owners. This behavior can be set in the workspace settings.

If you want to be sure that your bot can delete message from others make sure its installed by an admin user and then use his access token (not the bot token).

Comment: OK, I read, and HOW can I install that Spring Boot appication (via Webhook) that it gets the right permissions? Please elaborate.

Comment: you can't install via webhook. The rights are linked to the token you are using, see `slackToken` form your code

Comment: not sure how you got the token. but the normal approach is a Slack app that you install via Oauth. The user that installs it must an Admin for your code to work.